# How to solve a set of matrix equations where more than 1 vectors are unknown

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, equation

I am trying to solve a set of equations like follows with python:

```
X2 - C1*X3 = X1
X3 = k*(X4-C2)*sqrt(X2(1-X2))
AX4 = C3*b
```

where X2,X3 and X4 are unknown N-dimension(N is constant) vectors.C1,k,C2 are known constant scalars.b and X1 is known constant N-D vector.A is known N * N matrix.vector multiply vector means simply ' * ' in Python. sqrting a vector means every element in vector be square rooted. vector minus a scalar means every element minus it.

I tried fsolve in scipy but it doesn't accept 2-D inputs.what method can i use to solve this problem?

Comment: Flatten your vectors into 1-D array, solve the equation and reshape them back into N-dimensional vectors?

Comment: @str1ng I have thought of that but my mentor suggested me not to do so

Comment: I assume that C3 is also a known constant scalar.

Comment: @Reinderien i have meant "X3 =" , not"X3 -",sorry for misspelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't leave all of those variables as degrees of freedom. All but one of them is a simple function. Choosing `x2` as your sole degree of freedom leads to a simpler optimisation problem:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing
from typing import Annotated, TypeVar, Literal

from scipy.optimize import fsolve

DType = TypeVar('DType', bound=np.generic)
Vector = Annotated[numpy.typing.NDArray[DType], Literal['N']]
Matrix = Annotated[numpy.typing.NDArray[DType], Literal['N', 'N']]


def implied_params(
    c1: float, c2: float, k: float,
    x1: Vector, x2: Vector,
) -> tuple[
    Vector,  # x3
    Vector,  # x4
]:
    # X2 - C1 * X3 = X1
    x3 = (x2 - x1)/c1

    # X3 = k * (X4 - C2) * sqrt(X2(1 - X2))
    x4 = (x3 / k / np.sqrt(x2*(1 - x2))) + c2

    return x3, x4


def equations(
    x2: Vector,
    x1: Vector,
    A: Matrix, b: Vector,
    c1: float, c2: float, c3: float, k: float,
) -> float:
    x3, x4 = implied_params(c1=c1, c2=c2, k=k, x1=x1, x2=x2)

    # AX4 = C3 * b
    return A@x4 - c3*b


def solve(
    A: Matrix, b: Vector,
    c1: float, c2: float, c3: float, k: float,
    x1: Vector,
) -> tuple[
    Vector,  # x2
    Vector,  # x3
    Vector,  # x4
]:
    x2 = fsolve(
        func=equations,
        args=(x1, A, b, c1, c2, c3, k),
        x0=np.full_like(x1, fill_value=0.5),
    )
    x3, x4 = implied_params(c1=c1, c2=c2, k=k, x1=x1, x2=x2)
    return x2, x3, x4


def demo() -> None:
    n = 5
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    A = rand.random(size=(n, n))
    b, x1 = rand.random(size=(2, n))
    c1, c2, c3, k = rand.random(size=4)
    x2, x3, x4 = solve(A=A, b=b, c1=c1, c2=c2, c3=c3, k=k, x1=x1)

    print('A =')
    print(A)
    print('b =', b)
    print('  = A@x4 / c3')
    print('  =', A@x4/c3)
    print(f'c = {c1:.6}, {c2:.6}, {c3:.6}')
    print(f'k = {k:.6}')
    print('x1 =', x1)
    print('   = x2 - c1*x3')
    print('   =', x2 - c1*x3)
    print('x2 =', x2)
    print('x3 =', x3)
    print('   = k*(x4 - c2)*sqrt(x2(1 - x2))')
    print('   =', k*(x4 - c2)*np.sqrt(x2*(1 - x2)))
    print('x4 =', x4)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()
```

```
A =
[[0.63696169 0.26978671 0.04097352 0.01652764 0.81327024]
 [0.91275558 0.60663578 0.72949656 0.54362499 0.93507242]
 [0.81585355 0.0027385  0.85740428 0.03358558 0.72965545]
 [0.17565562 0.86317892 0.54146122 0.29971189 0.42268722]
 [0.02831967 0.12428328 0.67062441 0.64718951 0.61538511]]
b = [0.38367755 0.99720994 0.98083534 0.68554198 0.65045928]
  = A@x4 / c3
  = [0.38367755 0.99720994 0.98083534 0.68554198 0.65045928]
c = 0.310242, 0.485835, 0.889488
k = 0.934044
x1 = [0.68844673 0.38892142 0.13509651 0.72148834 0.52535432]
   = x2 - c1*x3
   = [0.68844673 0.38892142 0.13509651 0.72148834 0.52535432]
x2 = [0.63693755 0.34375446 0.1581322  0.63977285 0.49016752]
x3 = [-0.16602911 -0.14558628  0.07425077 -0.26339285 -0.11341731]
   = k*(x4 - c2)*sqrt(x2(1 - x2))
   = [-0.16602911 -0.14558628  0.07425077 -0.26339285 -0.11341731]
x4 = [ 0.11619616  0.15766755  0.70370751 -0.10156709  0.24293609]
```